# Converting entire table to JSON data. Is there a better way?

Tags: php, sql, beginner, json, pdo

Building a 'card' database: I'm simply learning to take input data and store to database. Incorporating JSON, PDO, SQL, and enforcing my general coding skills through PHP, hopefully.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

$temp = array();
$data = array();

foreach($result as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $key2 => $val2){
        $temp[$key2] = $val2;
    }
    array_push($data, $temp);       
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Is there a better way to do what I am attempting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there sure is. Effectively, what you seem to be doing can be reduced to this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

I'll explain how I got to those three lines above, simplifying your code step by step.
The inner loop just *does not make sense*:

```
foreach($val as $key2 => $val2){
    $temp[$key2] = $val2;
}
array_push($data, $temp);
```

What this does, is iterate over `$val`, which is either an iterable object, or an array. When doing so, you're creating a new array `$temp`, which is, essentially an array-version of `$val`. Of course, `$temp` is never *"cleared"*, so the second time the inner loop is performed, `$temp` will be assigned new keys and values.
In short, suppose `$temp` looks like this, after the first iteration:

```
array('foo' => 123);
```

Then `$data` will look like this:

```
array(array('foo' => 123));
```

The second time, `$temp` might look like this:

```
array('bar' => 1234, 'foo' => 123);
```

Or, if `$val` had a key/property called `foo`, then `$temp['foo']` will simply be reassigned to the new value, and `$temp` will look like

```
array('foo' => 'new value');
```

Either way, `$data` will look like:

```
array(array('foo' => 123), array('foo' => 'new value'));
```

But why the loop? Why don't you simply *cast* the `$val` to an array, and push it into the `$data` array?

```
foreach($result as $val)
{//you're not using the $key anywhere, so you can omit it
    array_push($data, (array) $val);
}
```

That's a hell of a lot shorter, isn't it? But you can simplify this even more. You're fetching the result as objects, only to convert it to an array. Why don't you just fetch the results as an array from the off? Simply change:

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

To this:

```
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You won't need the loops at all after this.
Just as an asside, fetching the results of a query is often done using a `while` loop. I'll save you the inner-workings-details, but last time I checked, a `while` loop was actually marginally more performant than a `fetchAll` call... The only way to be sure is to benchmark both versions, but I tend to prefer the following:

```
$data = array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Ah well, the result is the same, anyway.

*Other thoughts:*
There are a couple of things you might want to consider, too:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
```

Is not the safest way to go about your business: What is the value of `$table`? If it's a value that comes from the client-side, who's to say it doesn't contain an invalid table name? something like `another_db.secret_table` would make for the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM another_db.secret_table
```

Fetching data that possibly wasn't intended for the client to see. That's a security issue. And a big one at that.
Next, the variable `$query` is not the best name. `PDO::prepare` returns an instance of `PDOStatement`, which is a *prepared statement*, which isn't a query anymore. That's why you often see the return value of `PDO::prepare` being assigned to a variable called `$stmt`.

Either way, with a query without a `WHERE` clause, prepared statements only cause more overhead. You're better of executing it from the off. Prepared statements are there when you want to insert variables into a query:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field = :fieldVal');
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':fieldVal' => $_POST['fieldVal']));
```

As an added bonus, you can re-use the same prepared statement over and over, to perform the same query a couple of times:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field = :fieldVal');
$vals = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach($vals as $val)
{
    echo 'Executing query with value: ', $val, PHP_EOL;
    $result = $stmt->execute(array(':fieldVal' => $val));
    //process $result...
}
```

The code above will perform the same query twice, once for the value *"foo"* and once with the value *"bar"*.

Comment: Thanks for all of the detail and explaination. I've learned a lot!